# how to export from sql to separate csv's based on column value

Tags: sql, pandas, ta-lib

I am querying sql where the raw OHLC and Volume and Ticker symbols are and calculating technical indicators with ta-lib library. I want to write the dataframe to csv (df.to_csv) for each individual ticker in the table. When I try to calculate the moving average, unfortunately, it lumps all tickers together and performs a running moving average across all of them instead of for each ticker symbol. By using FOR loop for each ticker, I hope to be able to calculate the values correctly and write to many different csv's.
here is what I have and I would like to know how to get "1.csv" replaced by my desired multiple output files.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
#import talib
from talib import (SMA)


DB_READ = {'servername': 'XYZ\XYZ',
      'database': 'olaptraderv4'}

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + DB_READ['servername'] + ';DATABASE=' +     DB_READ['database'] + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')


sql = """
SELECT [Ticker], [Date], [Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Volume] FROM    olaptraderv4.dbo.MiscHistorical order by Ticker
    """

for Ticker in sql:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    df.groupby('Ticker')
    df['SMA'] = SMA(df['Close'], timeperiod=30).round(3)
    df.to_csv('1.csv', index=False, header=True)
    print(df.tail(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in the SQL using a window function, although I'm unclear if you actually want to group teh result (needs `PARTITION BY` clause), or get it over the whole resultset:

```sql
SMA = AVG(Close) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
SMA = AVG(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY grouping_column ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Note that this only works by row-numbering, not actual date spans, so if you have multiple tickers on the same day you need a more complex solution.

Also, the first 29 rows will not have 30 rows of data to average, because there aren't those rows. You may still want the result.

Comment: Thanks but I actually have about 40 other technical indicators to calculate as well - so I need to use ta-lib. I just put SMA as an example here.